# Hibernate database operation error

Tags: java, hibernate

I use MyEclipse 10 under Windows can run normally, and run on Linux to use the Eclipse when they make a mistake. I will download a DTD to local (for Linux cannot access hibernate DTD address).

I just want to know why this is wrong? thank you

```
ERROR INFO：
<code>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Sep 02, 2013 11:42:55 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.5.Final}
Sep 02, 2013 11:42:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: `{hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, hibernate.max_fetch_depth=5, hibernate.format_sql=true, hibernate.generate_statistics=true, hibernate.connection.username=sa, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true, hibernate.connection.pool_size=5}`
Sep 02, 2013 11:42:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Sep 02, 2013 11:42:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Sep 02, 2013 11:42:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Sep 02, 2013 11:42:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/cdd/model/Medicine.hbm.xml
Sep 02, 2013 11:42:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.cdd.util.HibernateUtil
    at com.cdd.util.Delete.main(Delete.java:30)
Medicine medicine = (Medicine) session.load(Medicine.class,new Integer(1)); 

</code>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "/home/../dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping resource="com/cdd/model/Medicine.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Medicine.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "/home/puruidong/JavaEEworkspace/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.cdd.model.Medicine" table="tb_medicine">
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" not-null="true" length="200" />
        <property name="price" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="factoryAdd" length="200"/>
        <property name="description" type="text"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Medicine.java

```
Package the CDD. Model; 

Public class Medicine { 
Private Integer id; / / id no. 
Private String name; / / the name of the drug 
Private double price; / / price 
Private String factoryAdd; / / the factory address 
Private String Description; / / description 
Public Integer getId () { 
Return the id; 
} 
Public void setId (Integer id) { 
This. Id = id; 
} 
Public String getName () { 
Return the name; 
} 
Public void elegantly-named setName (String name) { 
This. Name = name; 
} 
Public double getPrice () { 
The return price; 
} 
Public void setPrice (double price) { 
This. Price = price; 
} 
Public String getFactoryAdd () { 
Return factoryAdd; 
} 
Public void setFactoryAdd (String factoryAdd) { 
Enclosing factoryAdd = factoryAdd; 
} 
Public String getDescription () { 
Return the Description; 
} 
Public void setDescription (String description) { 
Description = the Description; 
} 
}
```

Delete.java

```
package com.cdd.util;

import com.cdd.util.HibernateUtil;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import com.cdd.model.Medicine;


public class Delete {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = null;         

        try {

            session = HibernateUtil.getSession();

            session.beginTransaction();

            Medicine medicine = (Medicine)session.load(Medicine.class, new Integer(1));

            session.delete(medicine);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }finally{

            HibernateUtil.closeSession(session);
        }
    }
}
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
package com.cdd.util;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory factory = null;

    static {
        try {

            Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();

            factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Session getSession() {

        Session session = (factory != null) ? factory.openSession() : null;
        return session;
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return factory;
    }

    public static void closeSession(Session session) {
        if (session != null) {
            if (session.isOpen()) {
                session.close(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Directory that's right, has been tested.

Comment: Is that the full stacktrace? My guess would be that your `static` code block is throwing a `RuntimeException` so cannot be loaded. You probably have a database permissions problem.

Comment: HibernateUtil. Java is class I handle database is initialized, then how should I rewrite the class? But the class under the MyEclipse run completely without error.

Comment: Database is the root account, that I use is mysql5.1 database version